# Compare item in a vector to all items in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

So I currently have a vector of my custom struct.

Each element in my vector is a graph point (x,y). Given an index in my vector, I need to be able the euclidean distance between the index given and all the other points. I already know how to calculate euclidean distance, **what I want to know is how I can check any element in my vector against all the others without rotating.**

For example in my vector if I have:

(3,5) , (4,6) , (7,8) , (5,3)

as an example and I was given index 2 (7,8) I need to be able to calculate the distance between (7,8) and the other 3 points because I'm interested in finding the shortest path. I thought of using the std::rotate function and move (7,8) to the front but I don't want to mess with my vector. **Is there a way I can accomplish being given an index in my vector to an element and comparing it to all other elements in the vector without changing the vector so I can do my computations? Thank you**

Comment: Have you tried a simple loop through the vector from front to back, ignoring the one element you are comparing?

Comment: Oh wow I haven't tried that! That makes so much sense! Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but please remember to mark the below answer as accepted if it was the solution, or write your own answer explaining what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(const auto& i : yourvector)
  compare(i, yourvector[foo]);
```

That ought to do it if looping through the vector is OK.

Else you can `sort` the vector to put the closest elements first: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: [`std::find_if` may also be helpful.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)